# Fmath lib does not support full Latex Character?

Tags: apache-flex, latex

I am using Fmath Lib to display latex in my Adobe air app. But some latex equation does not display right.Examples are "\supseteq" ,"\underline{a}",... Does Fmath lib for flex not support full Latex character?

Comment: Please show your code example so we can try to help.